# how to deploy asp.net mvc 3 where LINQ to SQL Classes is used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, linq-to-sql

i'm new in `LINQ`.I have used `LINQ` to `SQL` class in my `asp.net mvc 3`.now when it comes to deployment in `iis` how can i manage connection ?i'm stuck here.help plz ,thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you managing the connection via `Web.config`?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="MyConnectionString"/>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="XXXXXXXXXX"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You should verify that the connectionStrings is pointing to the right SQL server

*edit-1*

Just to be sure we are on the same page on "managing the connection via Web.config" I mean via the partial class:

```
public partial class MyDataContext{
    public MyDataContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString,mappingSource)
    {
    }
}
```

And of course you need to change also:
[image: Connection-ApplicationSettings-True]